# How can I preserve a pandas multi-index between a to_excel() and a read_excel()?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

According to the pandas documentation for [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html), I can put the index column names on a separate line and then the method will **which columns should be used as indices.**

I want to create an Excel file from a multi-indexed dataframe that can be read in as such, but I can't figure out how to get pandas to write [to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) in such a way that this additional row is created (from a multi-indexed dataframe).

I can't imagine that storing a multi-indexed dataframe as an Excel worksheet and then pulling it back in later is that uncommon a use case, so I'm wondering if I just haven't figured out how to do this.

Here's an example of a dataframe I'd like to 'freeze' in Excel before reading back in without having to tell read_excel which columns are the indices:

```
ipdb> my_df
                             Date         Amount
Rec Section             Row                         
0   Top Section         2    2015-05-01      -105.00
1   Middle Section      3    2015-05-04     90247.60
2   Middle Section      4    2015-05-05     -2992.99
3   Bottom Section      5    2015-05-08      -800.00
```

In my example, there are three index columns: Rec, Section, and Row.

When I write this to Excel and then read it back in, I don't want to have to tell it this. Since read_excel seems to have a method that infers the index names when they appear on a separate row, I want to have it just figure it out (assuming I correctly write the Excel file).

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post example code of your dataframe (simplified).

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the same issue when trying to write a pivot table to Excel.  I was able to get this to work by modifying the `frame.py` file in `../pandas/core`.  Changing `if self.columns.nlevels > 1` to `if self.columns.nlevels > 1 and not index` got me what I needed.

As this functionality is still not supported by `Pandas`, you may still encounter funny output.  Also, this will likely not solve the issue for `read_excel` either. Hopefully this helps a little!

I referenced 'onesandzeros' in his [GitHub comment](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9794).

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting a good answer. As an FYI, I added backticks to format your code reformatted your link (my edits won't show up until they've been peer reviewed).

Comment: Oh, awesome. Thank you Richard, I will be sure to format my future answers similarly! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Figuring out the small formatting details on SO can be hard. :)