# How can I make pandas.to_excel() include the index but NOT on a separate line?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When I save a Pandas DataFrame to Excel (with the index option left as it's default: True), the resulting Excel file has a line beneath the row of headers. Said row contains the index name. How can I avoid that extra line and just have the index name(s) show up in the same row as the rest of the column headers?

```
df[field_list].to_excel(path)
```

I don't see this addressed in [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel).

In the context of [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167246/how-can-i-preserve-a-pandas-multi-index-between-a-to-excel-and-a-read-excel), I could understand how it would be useful to put the indices on their own line (so that pandas, in reading an Excel file back in, could identify index columns), but since that doesn't seem to work (unless something's changed or I'm mistaken), I don't know why it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that setting merge_cells (which is by default True) to False accomplishes the objective, but it's not immediately clear to me why that's the case.

```
df[field_list].to_excel(path, merge_cells=False)
```